# How to remove caps on circular faucet handles?

Tags: leak, faucet, sink, bathroom-fixtures

My faucet is leaking from the base of the handle so I need to replace the cartridge or rubber seat.  I'm having trouble removing the cap to the handle to change the cartridge and rubber seat.

I don't know what brand the faucet set is but it might be Delta since all the other faucet sets in the house are Delta.

[image: sink faucet1]

As the photo shows, the handles are circular.  The caps on top of the handles don't seem to come off by twisting counter-clockwise.  I also looked around to see if there's a notch to stick a screwdriver into to pop it off.  No notch either.  I checked for a set screw too.  No set screw on the handle.

Someone else suggested there might be some mineral deposits around the caps so I tapped the cap/faucet with a rubber mallet.  It still doesn't come off.

As an example of why I thought we need to twist counter-clockwise, one of our shower handles have a similar handle type.  I was able to twist the cap off with a counter-clockwise motion to expose the screw to remove the handle.

[image: shower faucet1]
[image: shower faucet cap off]

I tried to find installation instructions on Delta's website for their Monitor faucet set that looks like what I have but again, no luck.  I'm running out of ideas on how to remove the cap without resorting to using an oscillating tool to cut the cap or faucet off.

Can anyone tell me what else to try to get the cap off the faucet handle?  Thanks.

Comment: Apply more force when twisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to remove the cap by using 2 channel lock pliers and some strips of rubber I cut from a sheet of rubber.  The rubber was used to help me grip the cap and the faucet without doing TOO much damage to it from the pliers' teeth.

I gripped the faucet to hold it steady with 1 channel lock plier and used another to grip and turn the cap off.  Easy-peasy

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, its similar to the shower control.

You need to unscrew the cap anti-clockwise.
There is a good chance that there is a decades worth of crud jamming the cap.  You could trying pouring hot water (from a kettle) over.  this may dissolve some crud, and may also loosen it by expansion.
You could try using a "jar-opening" gripper, to ensure you have a really good grip.
Alternatively, try wrapping cello-tape around the knob as protection, then CAREFULLY using multi-grip pliers.